# How to display items from List in C# (console application)

Tags: c#, list, show

```
public class Program
{
    public static List<Players> DB = new List<Players>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose action: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'Register', 'Deposit', 'Withdraw' or 'Info' to continue.");
    }

    static void Register()
    {
        Players Player = new Players();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Register New Player");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type Username:");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Player.username = username;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type Fisrt Name:");
        string firstname = Console.ReadLine();
        Player.firstname = firstname;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type Last Name:");
        string lastname = Console.ReadLine();
        Player.lastname = lastname;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type Birth Date:");
        string birthdate = Console.ReadLine();
        Player.birthdate = birthdate;

        DB.Add(Player);
    }

}
```

So I'm asking how I can show items that are stored in DB list? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: In fact i have more code. its above the main method:
 public static List<Players> DB = new List<Players>();

So how i can get info from list in this case?

Comment: Well, at the moment you're not showing any code that tries to show the items stored in DB. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to describe the behavior you're hoping to see and the behavior you're actually seeing? Explain what you've tried to achieve the desired behavior and why it is not working. It's hard to help someone solve a problem when the problem itself is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like

```
Foreach(Player p in DB) { Console.WriteLine(p.firstname); }
```